# Can we correlate the residuals from the their outcome parts in Heckman model?

Tags: heckman

Let's say we have two Heckman selection models. Can we correlate the residuals from the their outcome parts (since they might have different lengths)? If yes, how?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Probably it would be best if you wrote down your model as part of the question.

Comment: What I mean is that two heckman selection models imply 4 equation ( 2 for outcomes and 2 for selection). After selection outcomes might differ in lengths.